# Request had insufficient authentication scopes 403 youtube api video update

Tags: youtube-data-api

Getting below error while trying to update video title through youtube data api v3. The token was retrieved using command 'gcloud auth print-access-token'. Please suggest how to include update scope in the oauth token

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Insufficient Permission",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "method": "youtube.api.v3.V3DataVideoService.Update",
                    "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```